# Efficient SQL table merge and paginate

Tags: sql, node.js, bigdata

I have 5 distinct tables namely:

- deposits
- withdrawals
- payments
- transfers
- exchanges

I need to merge these tables and return a paginated result from a `Nodejs` API to clients. I don't know how to do this efficiently, given that the tables are really big(>100K rows each).

I was thinking of 2 approaches that I can take.

1. Stream individual query results from each table to the node js backend and implements some merging logic there.

OR

2. Somehow perform the merging at DB level, by creating some sort of virtual table or some persisted view, and perform a query on that.

What do you guys think?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please show the structure of these table for us being able to help more precisely. In general I would say, the most performant way to do something with data bases is on the data base, e.g. with a view or a prepared statemtent with an efficient join.

Comment: In the database, is there a common "Transactions" table (I'd be surprised if there wasn't)? If so why not do the pagination from it?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: There are many ways you can do it, like denormalizing the tables. You need to provide more information regarding your infrastructure, database, indexes, and the queries you expect to run etc...

Comment: For which purpose you need the data from those tables?
Is it a report? Are you are going to calculate something based on those records?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to manipulate with DB data then from my perspective the most efficient way accomplishing this would be on DB level, composing the specific SQL view or preparing advanced query leveraging combine techniques via [JOIN](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-12-introduction-to-database-joins/), [UNION](https://www.essentialsql.com/learn-to-use-union-intersect-and-except-clauses/) or *[Sub queries](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-19-introduction-to-sub-queries/)*. Saying above, and assuming [*Node.js*](https://nodejs.org/en/) Streaming [concept](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#streaming), it is always good practice adopting streaming against large datasets.

```
const request = new sql.Request()
request.stream = true // You can set streaming differently for each request
request.query('select * from verylargetable')
```

If you will expect to further use this data for some other client applications, you may consider using [CSV stringifier](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-stringify) Node.js package, converting SQL output data into CSV text format.

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to provide a solution without knowing the structure of tables. You can use a view created by using INNER JOIN and use that view to select the attributes to return data to API requests Or U can Directly use INNER JOIN to return data. Return Data using procedure.